# Importing CSV file with django-adaptors: A Db model should not have any csv field defined

Tags: python, django, csv, django-adaptors

I am trying to import csv file to my SQL database. Here is my models:

```
class Matchups(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    vs_Ashe = models.CharField(max_length=140)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.name)

class MyCsvModel(CsvDbModel):
    name = CharField()
    vs_Ashe = CharField()

    class Meta:
        dbModel = Matchups
        delimiter = ","
```

While trying to import csv file:  `my_csv_list = MyCsvModel.import_data(data = open("/home/irmantas/ADC.csv"))`

I get this error:

```
A Db model should not have any csv field defined.
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're using 'CsvDbModel' and should no longer defined fields, your class should look:

```
class MyCsvModel(CsvDbModel):

  class Meta:
    dbModel = Matchups
    delimiter = ","
```

Otherwise you should be using 'CsvModel' instead:

```
class MyCsvModel(CsvModel):
  name = CharField()
  vs_Ashe = CharField()

  class Meta:
    dbModel = Matchups
    delimiter = ","
```